# Google Messaging Service 8.3 brings ZipException error

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-multidex

I'm trying to figure out how to solve this sudden *duplicate entry* problem:

```
Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:com/google/android/gms/internal/zzqq$zza.class
```

I have just increased Google Cloud Messaging version from *8.1* to **8.3**.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'
}
```

Any pointer?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

My `build.gradle`

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion project.properties['compileSdkVersion'].toInteger()
    buildToolsVersion project.properties['buildToolsVersion']

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion project.properties['minSdkVersion']
        targetSdkVersion project.properties['targetSdkVersion'].toInteger()
        versionCode project.properties['versionCode'].toInteger()
        versionName project.properties['versionName']
        multiDexEnabled true

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

dependencies {
    compile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version")
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Something similar is happening with 8.4, too

```
Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForFabricStagingDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: 
duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzat.class
```

Comment: post your `build.gradle`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you upgraded from `8.1`? Users have been reporting this as a known bug when upgrading from `7.8` to `8.1`: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=187464

Anyways, just stay on the highest version which is still working for you, until they fix it in a later version.

Comment: Yep, I'm staying on the 8.1 for now.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the conflict is caused by one of the libraries in my project. It's using `play-services-ads:8.1` and, apparently, being shrinked/obfuscated with Proguard, it ends to contain a `zzat.class` file, similar to the one contained in `play-services-basement:8.4.0`.
I'm trying to solve this issue forcing `play-services-ads` to use a newer version with this change in my `build.gradle`:

```
configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy {
    force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
  }
}
```

This could have side effects in particular scenarios, but, right now, it seems to be the only fix.

Comment: I still get an error: `Error:Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging$1.class`